# How to do $("#side1").css("transform","translateX(-100px) scale(1)") using jquery animate?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, css-transforms

```
if(flag==0)
{
    $("#side1").css("z-index","999");
    $("#side2").css("z-index","9");
    $("#side3").css("z-index","9");
    $("#side1").css("transform","translateX(0px) scale(1.5)");
    $("#side2").css("transform","translateX(-100px) scale(1)");
    $("#side3").css("transform","translateX(100px)");
    flag=1;
}
```

I need to use jquery animate to do this instead of css is there anyway to do this not using any plugins?

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to set initial styles of your element "#side1", animate() method will transform your initial styles to newer one.

```
$("#side1").animate({
    transform: "translateX(0px) scale(1.5)",
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Things to do when animation is complete.
});
```

5000 in this example is duration of animation in milliseconds.